# <h2> interfering with vertical-align of inline divs

Tags: css, html, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have two inline divs, the second of which uses vertical-align:top.  The problem is that the second div begins with a h2 and then followed by some content, and h2 by definition doesn't listen to vertical-align.  So the h2 is dragging down the rest of the contents.  How do I fix that?

```
<div style="display:inline;">
<img src="" width=300 height=600>
</div>

<div style="display:inline; vertical-align:top;">
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>
Paragraph of text
</p>
</div>
```

The fix worked thanks to the answers from @Ishan Jain and @Hiral.  I now have a similar problem with two nested divs in the original right div.  New code:

```
<div style="display:inline;">
<img src="" width=300 height=600>
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
<h2>Heading</h2>

<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
<h4>Heading</h4>
<img src="" width="350" height="233">
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
<h4>Heading</h4>
<img src="" width="350" height="191">
</div>
<p>
    Paragraph of text
</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `display:inline-block;` for make div inline.
This property allows a DOM element to have all the attributes of a block element, but keeping it inline.

Use this: `style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;"`

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/xF3Pp/)

Or just try to make your first div `float:left`:

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/nN3PA/1/)

Comment: Great, it worked!  I have now added two nested divs inside the original right div, and they are refusing to align again.  I have added display:inline-block and vertical-align:top properties to each of the nexted divs, but that hasn't worked.  I am adding the new code to the original question.

Comment: Ok, Can you please provide a JsFiddle.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the are missed aligned. But It's caused by img element width. Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hgN9U/2/

Comment: This is weird.  When "Paragraph of text" is replaced with something much longer, like a real block of text, all the divs drop below the original left div again.

Comment: It's because Paragraph  tag is a block element and if you put large content inside a Paragraph tag. it's cover full width. So you can use "word-break" CSS property with fixed width. Try jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hgN9U/3/

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, everything works fantastic now.  I also fixed the problem with the width of img elements by adding a parent container div with a fixed width.  They no longer carry over after that.

Comment: A new problem now.  That paragraph has words broken up in random places due to the word-break property, so it doesn't look like proper text.  Is there any way around that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42259/discussion-between-ishan-jain-and-knocks-x)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="" width=300 height=600>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    display:inline-block; //change from inline to inline-block
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nN3PA/)